# Translating a Plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I am trying to understand plane equations but am finding it a bit confusing.  My understanding of the plane equation says that for points that lie in the plane they will give an output of $0$ i.e. $f(x) = 0$.  If I want to define a plane that gives an output of 1 then I have $f(x)=1$, but isn't this the same as $f(x) - 1 = 0$, so it would be the same as defining a plane that has an intercept that is $1$ lower.

Why is it that when I see diagrams they show that the line is shifted away from the origin i.e. with a higher intercept?  Why does it not now have a lower intercept?

Comment: As the answers have shown, the claim in the first paragraph is incorrect: depending on the exact nature of the function $f$ that defined the plane, subtracting $1$ could give you an intercept that is greater or lesser by any amount. And without an explicit example, I think the second paragraph is unanswerable. We don't know what diagrams you've seen or what equations were associated with them.

Answer (score 2):

Planes can be defined as
$$Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$$
where $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}.$ According to your definition, you would have $$f(x,y,z) = Ax + By + Cz + D.$$
For each constante value $k\in\mathbb{R}$, the equation $f(x,y,z)=k$ defines a different plane. In fact, for any function $f$, these are the so called [level sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set). Anyhow, as you said, you can always redefine (translate) your function so that the surfaces fulfills the homogeneous equation:
$$f(x,y,z)=k \implies g(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z)-k = 0$$

Adding or multiplying the equation by constants does not change the surface that it represents, but it does change the function for which you are choosing a level set. in other words, $f(x,y,z) = k$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$ represent the same surface (a plane), but they arise from different level sets.

Note also that, for $C\ne0$
$$Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 \iff A'x + B'y + z = D',$$
where $A'=A/C$, $B'=B/C$ and $D'=-D/C$. This new equation still represents the same plane (but a level set of a different function!). But, in this case, $D'$ can be interpreted as the height, from the origin, where the plane cuts the $z$-axis. Of course, you can deduce analogous information for the other axes by transforming the equation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I suggest you how to see the question for a straight line, and you can extend easily to a plane.
A stright line has equation:
$$
f(x)=0 \iff ax+by+c=0
$$

If $b \ne 0$ the intercept with the $y$ axis is given by:

$$
x=0 \Rightarrow by+c=0\Rightarrow y=-\frac{c}{b}
$$

If you write the new equation:
$$
ax+by+c=1
$$
you find:
$$
x=0 \Rightarrow by+c=1\Rightarrow y=-\frac{c}{b}+\frac{1}{b}
$$
and, depending on the signs of $b$ and $c$, this adds or subtract something to the first intercept.